# PHP OpenSSL openssl_get_cert_locations

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

My phpinfo is showing this:

`OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`

I am still getting this error:

`Call to undefined function openssl_get_cert_locations`

What am I missing? Even **openssl_get_privatekey** is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[openssl_get_cert_locations](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cert-locations.php) is available starting from PHP5 version >= 5.6.0

Type in console `php -v` and let us know what you see.

Comment: it is 5.5.9 so I think there is no chance for me to see this.